# File object cannot upload to server in safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, safari, ng-file-upload

Task is to make a file in the browser and then upload it on the server.
I have created blob object and then created file object in browser and then upload it on the server.

```
var file = [new File([data],'-Invoice.pdf', {type: 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8;'})];
```

File successfully created in safari but when I call for the upload, server respond me with 404 i-e file not found error.
Working perfectly in chrome/firefox.
Used npm module express-fileupload on server side.
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

A difference in browser shouldn't affect the server-side uploading. You should double check that you have the file when you make the call to your server.

I am assuming that you didn't use their file upload buttons. Try following their html guidelines for uploading and it should work, although I haven't tested in Safari.

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
console.log(file.length); // if less than 1 or undefined, then your problem is probably in the html. I 
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
        data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```